# Call External app and wait for results without blocking out other tasks

Tags: c#

I have a VBA class that needs to come forward to the C# .net world to support vendor migration to a back end web API. Adding API calls for Web services in VBA is not efficient use of resources.  Using C# for the explicit COM interface has proven better than VB.Net implicit COM tools. There is no user interface in the Class.

The current solution uses a local EXE that processes a file and provides a response file. The vendor is working to eliminate the EXE and replace with Web API. This application(EXE) has some quirks that I've coded around in order for it to be able to do it's thing. This uses a series of Sleep and DoEvents calls to allow the app to run. I must continue to support and use the EXE until vendor dictates otherwise.

The EXE's quirks are that it can only process 1 file at a time, does not close after completion of the processing, will not process another file if left open, and will not run if drops to background.

I must re-code existing functionality and then be able to "switch to" new web API once vendor migrates an account.

Have converted most functionality except the Wait for the response file and still give time slices to the Launched EXE, Tried Sleep and get deadlock of launched APP. So looking for how to correctly launch EXE, let it process and check for exclusive access to response file. This needs to timeout after x seconds so operator can force a quit or continue to retry.

Below is the VBA code used to handle the requirement

```
      'Vars are set elsewhere removed as not code in question.

  ReturnValue = Shell((sDazPath & sDazEXE & " " & mPrintFileIn), vbMinimizedFocus)
  On Error Resume Next
  AppActivate ReturnValue
  On Error GoTo 0

  DoEvents
  Count1 = 0
  Wait4File = True
  Do While Wait4File And Count1 < lWaitCnt 'lWaitCount is set elsewhere
    Count1 = Count1 + 1
    Wait4File = Not FileDoneGrowing(mPrintFileOut) 'function returns true if done
    If Wait4File And Count1 >= lWaitCnt Then
      sTemp = "Unsuccessful import of Postage results. " & vbCrLf
      sTemp = sTemp & "You may wait to see if a label prints and then retry import. "
      sTemp = sTemp & " If no label prints check internet access and/or Endicia Network "
      sTemp = sTemp & "Status." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you wish to re-try Endicia import?"
      sPopAsk = PSI.msg(sTemp, "Processing Result Import", psiMsgHelp, "Yes", "No")
      If sPopAsk = "Yes" Then
        Wait4File = Not FileDoneGrowing(mPrintFileOut) 'function returns true if done
        Count1 = 0
      End If
    End If
  Loop


  '============================== END Code that Starts and waits

  Private Function FileDoneGrowing(sPathFilename As String) As Boolean

  Dim fs As Object
  Dim f As Object
  Dim lLastSize As Long
  Dim lCurSize As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim iFileNo As Integer
  Dim bOk As Boolean

  bOk = False
  lLastSize = 0
  If ValidFile(sPathFilename) Then

    'get initial sizes
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(sPathFilename) 'processing from this one
    lLastSize = f.Size
    DoEvents 'give other things a chance
    Set f = Nothing
    For i = 0 To 500 'just pause a moment
      DoEvents 'Let system think
    Next
    Set f = fs.GetFile(sPathFilename) 'processing from this one
    lCurSize = f.Size
    Set f = Nothing

    Do While (lLastSize <> lCurSize) Or (lCurSize = 0)
      lLastSize = lCurSize
      For i = 0 To 500 'just pause a moment
        DoEvents 'Let system think
      Next
      Set f = fs.GetFile(sPathFilename) 'processing from this one
      lCurSize = f.Size
      Set f = Nothing
      DoEvents
    Loop

    bOk = IIf(lLastSize = lCurSize, True, False)
  Else 'no file not done!
    bOk = False
  End If

  DoEvents

  If bOk Then 'we think the file is done growing, can we get exclusive access?
    On Error Resume Next
    iFileNo = FreeFile(0)
    Open sPathFilename For Binary Lock Read Write As #iFileNo
    If Err.Number Then 'if no error we have exclusive access
      bOk = False
    Else
      Close #iFileNo
    DoEvents
    End If
  End If
  FileDoneGrowing = bOk

End Function
```

Below is what I have so far in C#:

```
/// <summary>
/// Calls the Daz application to process the XML file, sets return properities as available.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>0=Success; -#=Internal fail; #=Result/error from call</returns>
private int DazLabelRequest()
{

  Message = "";
  int iOk = -299;
  int iDazRunning = -200;

  //ToDo: Build out Daz Label Request call
  Message = "Not Implemented DazLabelRequest"; //Debug only (Not Implemented)
  iDazRunning = LaunchDazApp("");

  //Debug: Blow off about a minute then kill app.
  Thread.Sleep(10000);

  //Todo: add code to verify we've received response file.
  //Don't add response time with just sleep check for result file done growing, then verify readability
  //then close Daz and parse results.

  if (iDazRunning == 0)
  {
    iDazRunning = CloseDazApp();
  }
  return iOk;
}

private int FindDazWindow()
{
  Process[] DazProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Daz");
  return (DazProc.Length > 0) ? 0 : -1;
}

/// <summary>
/// Launces the Daz Exe with a parameter of XML file to process
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Integer: 0=Success, -# failed</returns>
private int LaunchDazApp(string XML_FQN)
{

  long lRetries = 0;
  int iDazFound = -201;

  Daz = new Process();
  ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

  StartInfo.FileName = DazAppFQN;
  StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
  if (!NED.IsBlankStr(XML_FQN))
  {
    StartInfo.Arguments = XML_FQN;
  } 
  Daz = Process.Start(StartInfo);

  //if (!Daz.HasExited)
  //{
    lRetries = 0;
    while (FindDazWindow() != 0 && lRetries <= RetryCount)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(250);
      lRetries++;
    }

    iDazFound = FindDazWindow();
    if (iDazFound != 0)
    {
      Message = "Daz window not found, either took too long or failed to launch.";
      return -201;
    } //Daz should launch within a timely manner. Fail safe check here.
  //} //if(Daz.Start())

  return 0; //we're good to go.
}

private int CloseDazApp()
{
  int iOK = 0;

  try
  {
    Daz.Kill();
    Daz.Close();
    return 0;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

    iOK = -99;
  }
  return iOK;
}
```

Comment: Please provide code examples. It's difficult to advise proper code patterns without seeing the code.

Comment: Below is the VBA code used to handle the requirement

Comment: Why use the external Daz application to process XML files? .Net has lots of libraries for parsing/reading XML files.

Comment: It is not an XML processor, it's a front end to a shipping process. It accepts XML formatted data and responds with results.   So I must create the xml for the program and then parse the programs response file which is XML.  Believe me I'd like to loose it but there are costs involved for my customers.  my real need is to pump the windows message queue so the program gets some time to do it's work.  I'm not finding a way to replace the VBA/VB.net doevents process.